# Pegar "output" de comando Lua

Tags: lua

Quero pegar o Output de um comando lua e armazenar em uma string.
EX:
print(1)
output->1
getOutput("print(1)")
Gostaria de armazenar o valor retornado em uma string, nesse caso, 1.

Algo como um debugger, ele executaria o comando e armazenaria o resultado em uma string.

Consegui!

```
a= "print('stackoverflow')"
b = loadstring(a)
print(b())
```

Mas eu queria que mostrasse se tivesse um erro também.

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer. Tente montar um código que mostre alguma coisa. Explique com detalhes. Diga onde você quer chegar, pode ser que exista outra forma de fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Ja sim, mas eu queria que indicasse o erro, desculpe nao ter sido claro. 
EX: attempt to call a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

A função loadstring tem um retorno assim:

Se sucesso:

- Retorno #1: Função
- Retorno #2: true

Se erro:

- Retorno #1: false
- Retorno #2: string contendo mensagem de erro

Alem disso, existe a função pcall que chama uma outra e retornar se houve sucesso.

Funciona da mesma maneira, a diferença que do segundo retorno em diante, ela retorna o que você retornou.

Basciamente:

```
local ret,err = loastring(str)
if not ret then
   print(err)
else
   ret,err = pcall(ret,...)
   if not ret then
      print(err)
   end
end
```